# errors when I try to add google sign in to my project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, google-signin, pubspec

> Because google_sign_in >=5.4.0 depends on
> google_sign_in_platform_interface ^2.2.0 which depends on quiver
> ^3.0.0, google_sign_in >=5.4.0 requires quiver ^3.0.0. And because
> every version of dependencies depends on quiver ^2.0.1, google_sign_in
> '>=5.4.0 is incompatible with dependencies. So, because daheeh depends on both dependencies any and google_sign_in ^6.0.2, version solving
> failed. pub get failed (1; So, because daheeh depends on both
> dependencies any and google_sign_in ^6.0.2, version solving failed.)

I try to delete build and flutter clean without result.(I don't have quiver package and I didn't use it at all)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like issue is with dependencies in your project(clean and pubget may not resolve this issue).
The **google_sign_in** package requires latest version of quiver than what your other dependencies are using,
which I think is the cause of conflict.

Try updating your dependencies to their latest versions
and see if that resolves the issue. You can do this by running
**flutter pub upgrade**

If it doesn't work, you have to manually update the conflicting dependencies
in your **pubspec.yaml** file to versions that are compatible with each other.
Try updating the **google_sign_in** dependency to a version that uses an older version of **quiver**,
or updating the other dependencies to use a newer version of **quiver**.

Answer (score 0):

remove version number  `google_sign_in:` or downgrade version number of library
' google_sign_in '  until be compatibale with other library

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the version of your libs, do you really need to use the latest?
Try downgrade, and fix the google_sign_in version for one which depends on google_sign_in_platform_interface version which depends on quiver 2.0.1